# Monotone increasing sequence converging probability wise implies convergence almost surely

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, proof-verification

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ be a probability space.

> Let $X,X_j\in m\mathcal F, j\in\mathbb N$, $X_1\leq X_2\leq\ldots$ such that $X_n\to X$ by probability. Show that $X_n\to X$ almost surely.

By letting $A_n(\varepsilon) := \{\omega : |X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)|>\varepsilon\}$, it's sufficient to show
$$(\forall\varepsilon > 0)\left (\mathbb P (\limsup _n A_n(\varepsilon))=0\right ). $$

To show the above it's also sufficient to show for every $\varepsilon >0$ the series $\sum _n \mathbb P (A_n(\varepsilon))$ converges (and apply Borel-Cantelli's lemma).

Let $\varepsilon > 0$, we'll show the sequence
$$\sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb P(A_j(\varepsilon)), n\in\mathbb N $$
is a Cauchy sequence (therefore convergent) i.e we'll show 
$$\sum_{j=n+1}^{n+m}\mathbb P (A_j(\varepsilon))\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\qquad (m\in\mathbb N). $$ Fix $c>0$. Due to convergence $X_n\to X$ by probability, for some $N\in\mathbb N$
$$n>N \Longrightarrow \mathbb P(A_n(\varepsilon))< \frac{c}{m} \overset{??}\Longrightarrow \sum_{j=n+1}^{n+m}\mathbb P(A_j(\varepsilon))<c ?! \tag{*}$$

Wrong!
Fixing $c>0$, convergence in probability provides for every $m\in\mathbb N$ an index $N(m)\in\mathbb N$ with
$$n > N(m) \Longrightarrow \mathbb P(A_n(\varepsilon))<\frac{c}{m}. $$
Clearly, these indices may increase without bound, however,  we may note 
$$a\leq b \Longrightarrow A_n(b)\subseteq A_n(a). $$
Fix the smallest $N(m) =: N$. By monotonicity, we also have
$$A_{n+1}(\varepsilon)\subseteq A_n(\varepsilon), n\in\mathbb N $$
Therefore, the argument in $(*)$ doesn't depend on the choice of $m\in\mathbb N$.

Still wrong! There is also the choice of $\varepsilon$ to take into account. There is no hope of remedying that. This approach is doomed to fail.

Comment: For Cauchy convergence, you need to show that $\sum_{j=n+1}^{n+m}\mathbb P (A_j(\varepsilon))$ converges to $0$ as *both* $m$ and $n$ go to infinity.

Comment: The logical error is that your choice of $N$ depends, not just on $\epsilon$, but also on $m$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This argument will not work. Suppose for instance $U$ is uniform on $[0,1]$ and $X_n=\mathbf1_{\{U\ge1/\sqrt{n}\}}$. Then $X_n\le X_{n+1}$ for all $n$, and $X_n\to1$ almost surely. However, taking $\varepsilon=\frac12$,
$$P(A_n(\varepsilon))=P(U<\tfrac1{\sqrt{n}})=\tfrac1{\sqrt{n}},$$
so $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(A_n(\varepsilon))=\infty$.

The problem is Borel-Cantelli provides you with a *sufficient* condition for almost sure convergence, but not a *necessary* one. However, the real proof is actually much simpler. Since $X_n\le X_{n+1}$, $Y(\omega):=\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n(\omega)$ exists pointwise, i.e. $X_n\to Y$ almost surely. Since almost sure convergence implies convergence in probability, $X_n\to X$ and $X_n\to Y$ in probability, which can easily be seen to imply $X=Y$ almost surely.

Comment: How do you define $1_X$?

Comment: $\mathbf1_A=1$ on the event $A$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: If $\omega\in S_n\subseteq S_{n+1}$ then $\mathbf1_{S_n}(\omega)=1=\mathbf1_{S_{n+1}}(\omega)$. If $\omega\notin S_n$ then $\mathbf1_{S_n}(\omega)=0\le\mathbf1_{S_{n+1}}(\omega)$.

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood. I drew a picture and I understand that part now.

Comment: Then $P(A_n(1/2)) = P(\{1_{U\geq 1/\sqrt{n}}<1/2\}) \overset{?} = 1/\sqrt{n}$ how is this probability computed?

Comment: The choice of $\varepsilon=\frac12$ is rather arbitrary. For $n$ large, $|\mathbf1_{S_n}-1|>\varepsilon$ if and only if $\mathbf1_{S_n}=0$, which occurs precisely on the event $U<\frac1{\sqrt{n}}$. By defintion of a uniform random variable, this event has probability $\frac1{\sqrt{n}}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68591/discussion-between-alvin-lepik-and-jason).

Answer (score 0):

Since $X_n\to X$ by probability, $\{X_n\}$ admits an subsequence $\{X_{n_i}\}$ such that $X_{n_i}\to X$ almost surely. Noting that $X_n$ is increasing, $X_n\to X$ almost surely.